# Can't find KepServerEx Alarm and events in OPC AE clients

Tags: plc, opc-ua, opc, kepserverex

I am using KepServerEx to monitor some PLC tags. I have defined some alarm tags in Area1 for testing. when I tried to access these tags in some clients like OpcExpert or UaExpert, I can find the Area1 folder but there is no tags inside. These clients have successfully read other tags. In OpcExpert I even cant find the server itself in alarm tab.

The AE connection to the server is enable and I am not using anonymous logins.

Any help appreciate